# How to use non standard ASCII charactors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my iPhone application I need to use a nonstandard character (which cannot insert using a keyboard directly) as a string separator. Then i need to store that string in a column in my sqlite db. When i read that string from the db, I need to use that special character to split that string.

For example lets Say # is a nonstandard char. Then Im going to create new string as 'firstname#lastname', and stored into database. Then I use that # to separate out the first name and last name from the database. Can any one help me to do that..??

Comment: What problem are you facing in doing that>?

Comment: What is your exact problem? You don't how to join strings using special character, or you don't know how to separate them or you don't know how to store them in DB? What is the real problem?

Comment: @VigneshI cannot use # value since some one may include # in firstname or lastname. then my logic is not going to work

Comment: @taskinoor Actully i dont know how to add nonstandard character to a NSString and also how to use it for split the NSString

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by nonstandard character. `#` is a standard ASCII character with ASCII value 35. You can use it in a string just like other characters.

Comment: @taskinoor I meant ASCII character with decimal value more than 128

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment as its not a direct answer to your question, but I have to ask...why do you need to do this? Why don't you store the two fields in separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join `firstName` and `lastName` using a `#`.

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@", firstName, lastName];
```

To get them back:

```
NSArray *components = [myStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSString *firstName = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lastName = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

You can use `#` just like any other character. And if you think that user may include `#` in names then you can use more complex combinations as suggested by Vignesh. Like this:

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#?%@", firstName, lastName];
NSArray *components = [myStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"#?"];
```

EDIT(after comment): If you want to use higher value than 128 then you can easily create a string by using `%C` modifier.

```
NSInteger val = 140;
NSString *separator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", val];
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", firstName, separator, lastName];
NSArray *components = [myStr componentsSeparatedByString:separator];
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, You need a separator character to join strings. The separator usage in real strings should be unlikely.

My idea is to use a combination of  characters. For ex '`#?`'.